# how can I write fuzzy logic for a stock market data

Tags: fuzzy-search, fuzzywuzzy, fuzzy-logic, fuzzy, fuzzy-comparison

`the purpose was to use fuzzy decision tree to predict future stock market price and relevant information retrieval for the stock. step are
i.   Fuzzification
ii.  Tree construction
iii. Defuzzification

This are some of my code.
`your text`fuzzy_sets = {}
`your text`for feature in feature_names:
`your text`feature_values = X[feature].values
`your text`fuzzy_sets[feature] = {}
`your text`fuzzy_sets[feature]['low'] = fuzz.trimf(feature_values, `your text`[np.min(feature_values), np.min(feature_values), `your text`np.mean(feature_values)])
`your text`fuzzy_sets[feature]['medium'] = fuzz.trimf(feature_values, `your text`[np.min(feature_values), np.mean(feature_values), `your text`np.max(feature_values)])
`your text`fuzzy_sets[feature]['high'] = fuzz.trimf(feature_values, [np.mean(feature_values), np.max(feature_values), np.max(feature_values)])
`your text`# Create fuzzy membership functions for the target variable

`your text`target_values = y.values
`your text`fuzzy_sets[target_name] = {}
`your text`fuzzy_sets[target_name]['low'] = fuzz.trimf(target_values, `your text`[np.min(target_values), np.min(target_values), np.mean(target_values)])
`your text`fuzzy_sets[target_name]['medium'] = fuzz.trimf(target_values, `your text`[np.min(target_values), np.mean(target_values), np.max(target_values)])
`your text`fuzzy_sets[target_name]['high'] = fuzz.trimf(target_values, `your text`[np.mean(target_values), np.max(target_values), np.max(target_values)])

[text](https://stackoverflow.com)# Create fuzzy membership functions for the target variable
`your text`target_values = y.values
`your text`fuzzy_sets[target_name] = {}
`your text`fuzzy_sets[target_name]['low'] = fuzz.trimf(target_values, `your text`[np.min(target_values), np.min(target_values), np.mean(target_values)])
`your text`fuzzy_sets[target_name]['medium'] = fuzz.trimf(target_values, `your text`[np.min(target_values), np.mean(target_values), np.max(target_values)])
`your text`fuzzy_sets[target_name]['high'] = fuzz.trimf(target_values, `your text`[np.mean(target_values), np.max(target_values), np.max(target_values)])

`your text`# Create the fuzzy decision tree
`your text`fuzzy_tree = {}
`your text`for feature in feature_names:
`your text`fuzzy_tree[feature] = `your text`ctrl.Antecedent(np.arange(np.min(X[feature]), np.max(X[feature]), `your text`np.mean(X[feature])), feature)
`your text`for fuzzy_set in fuzzy_sets[feature]:
`your text`fuzzy_tree[feature][fuzzy_set] = `your text`fuzz.trimf(fuzzy_tree[feature].universe, fuzzy_sets[feature][fuzzy_set])

`your text`target_variable = ctrl.Consequent(np.arange(np.min(y), np.max(y), `your text`np.mean(y)), target_name)
`your text`for fuzzy_set in fuzzy_sets[target_name]:
`your text`target_variable[fuzzy_set] = `your text`fuzz.trimf(target_variable.universe, fuzzy_sets[target_name][fuzzy_set])

`your text`# Print the fuzzy decision tree
`your text`print("Fuzzy Decision Tree:")
`your text`print(fuzzy_tree)
`your text`print(target_variable)

`your text`But i keep getting  error message in the process of creating the tree`